# Nginx SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share

Tags: nginx, ssl, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I got this error in nginx error log:

```
SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking
```

I use Let's Encrypt currently. Any ideas to solve this problem? Thank you, guys.

Comment: This is a bug in the client's TLS implementation -- either it sent key_share containing a group it doesn't support, or it responded to HelloRetryRequest with key_share other than the (single) requested group (which necessarily was already offered). This _probably_ doesn't have anything to do with your certificate from LE, but with bugs you never know. Identify the client and complain to its maintainer(s); if it's opensource (like the OpenSSL used in nginx) you could become a maintainer and complain to yourself :-)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I‘m running into the same problem after a Rails update to 6 on hatchbox.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**This isn't your problem.**

The best thing you can do in this situation is just to keep your server reasonably updated and secured.

At best for you, the client side of a request was running seriously outdated software, and at worst your server is simply being scanned for vulnerabilities by compromised devices connected to the internet.

Personally I lean in the direction of this being scanning, as I myself see these errors on a private development server, to which only I should ever have a legitimate reason to connect to, yet I see a ton of IP addresses mentioned by the error from around the world.

Similar question and answer has already been provided here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/905011/nginx-ssl-do-handshake-failed-ssl-error1417d18cssl/905019

Stay safe.

Comment: you should use a firewall. and maybe even a web application firewall.

Answer (score 5):

I was getting a similar error when I sent an HTTPS request from my computer in Iran to my server outside of Iran. Eventually I came to the conclusion that the problem is with our internet network (*maybe government filtering*) and using vpn solved the problem.

**Therefore, I recommend testing with vpn.**

Answer (score 0):

This may sound simple, but I was struggling with this issue because I was attempting to access `http://example.com` instead of `https://example.com`. It probably isn't your issue - but it worked for me.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail and show your nginx configuration.

Answer (score -1):

Check your secrete key decoupling with other settings.ini file
your app secret is not linking with variable you set

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say