# How to fix SSL_do_handshake() failed

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-20.04

After deployong a simple django app on aws EC2,I added ssl certficate using `python3-certbot-nginx` and everything worked fine. Initially I implemented ssl on `myapp1.com` by running `sudo certbot --nginx -d myapp1.com`. Later, I ran the command again but replacing `myapp1.com` with `www.myapp1.com`. and the process was successful. HTTPS was active when I entered the url on the browser. However, a soon as I restarted nginx all the webpages started displaying `404 Not Found nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)` when I assess the webpages using the IP-address, but `502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)` when I assess it using the domain name. I have searched through stack overflow for solution but none worked for my case. When I ran the command `/var/log/nginx/error.log` I grt the folllowing output:

```
2021/09/19 02:04:30 [notice] 323820#323820: signal process started
2021/09/19 02:08:20 [crit] 323821#323821: *478 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 107.178.231.248, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2021/09/19 02:12:12 [crit] 323821#323821: *498 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:141CF06C:SSL routines:tls_parse_ctos_key_share:bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 107.178.238.55, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2021/09/19 02:33:40 [notice] 324069#324069: signal process started
2021/09/19 02:35:12 [alert] 324102#324102: *4 open socket #13 left in connection 6
2021/09/19 02:35:12 [alert] 324102#324102: *5 open socket #14 left in connection 7
2021/09/19 02:35:12 [alert] 324102#324102: aborting
2021/09/19 02:35:34 [crit] 324125#324125: *1 connect() to unix:/var/www/html/myapp/app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 197.211.59.65, server: myapp1.com, request: "GET /admin/home/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/var/www/html/myapp/app.sock:/admin/home/", host: "myapp1.com", referrer: "https://myapp1.com/admin/"
```

```
# Default server configuration

server {

        # SSL configuration
        #
        #listen 443 ssl default_server;
        #listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        #
        # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
        #
        # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
        # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
        #
        # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
        # Don't use them in a production server!
        #include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name myapp1.com 18.189.167.3;

        location / {
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                include proxy_params;
                proxy_pass http://unix:/var/www/html/myapp/app.sock;
        
                #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location /static/ {
                autoindex on;
                alias /var/www/html/myapp/staticfiles/;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #       # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        #       # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
        location /phpmyadmin/
         {
                 root /usr/share/;
                index index.php;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp1.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myaoo1.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
```

How do I fix this issue? There are several conflicting solutions I found on the internet. I'm scared some approaches might cause other issues that might cause me to terminate the instance which will be too costly for me.

Comment: I researched after the error ID and urge you to read the answer to this post. It suggests that either your client ran outdated software or your development server is being scanned for vulnerabilities. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65854933/nginx-ssl-error141cf06cssl-routinestls-parse-ctos-key-sharebad-key-share